# iterate through only even/odd items with Java lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list that contains computed values and I can not change or transform the list to e.g. Map. I need to iterate through this list and get all the odd/even items. To do this with the old fashion Java `for loop` is quite easy.

**Let's say that I have this list:**

```
var results = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
```

**Get all odd items:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i += 2) {
    var current = results.get(i);
    process(current);
}
```

**Get all even items:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < results.size(); i += 2) {
    var current = results.get(i);
    process(current);
}
```

Can I get somehow the same result with lambda `forEach()` easily in one line?

**>UPDATE<**

Sorry for this, but I forgot to mention that the values actually are not numbers like 1, 2, 3, etc. I just used these values as an example. The solution must not rely on the value of the items.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, results.size() / 2).mapToObj(i -> results.get(i * 2)).forEach(this::process);`

Comment: @shmosel the above works only with even-sized lists. Try it with ["a","b","c"] and it will only select "a".

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Right, just add 1 to fix.

Answer (score 0):

### Based on your update to the question

You could do something like this:

```
// even elements
IntStream.range(0, results.size())
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .mapToObj(results::get)
                .forEach(this::process);

// odd elements
IntStream.range(0, results.size())
                .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
                .mapToObj(results::get)
                .forEach(this::process);
```

Comment: no worries @zappee, I just updated the answer accordingly, please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use `Stream.iterate`

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < results.size(), i -> i+2)
         .mapToObj(i -> results.get(i))
         .forEach(this::process);

IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i < results.size(), i -> i+2)
         .mapToObj(i -> results.get(i))
         .forEach(this::process);
```

Use `YourClass::process` if `process` a static method.